# An old movie about a boy who sells a condom as a balloon

Tags: identify-this-movie

This was a movie from 70~90ish, and it was a color film, not B&W.
I'm not sure of the plot of the whole movie, and where it was made as well.

But a boy was a main character and his parent sold condoms in their shop which became sensational in their small town. I remember a scene his mother shows people how to use the product. While she gives a presentation, she blows into a condom to make sure it doesn't have any holes. And the boy plays with a condom and put that on his foot and try putting in into a water basin and think of it as rubber socks, and he also makes a lot of balloons with condoms and sold it to the kids as a "balloon with a tip". His parents, aghast, rush to his vendor and pop every condom balloon and scolded him. Little later, a litter kid comes to the disappointed boy and asks the boy if he has any balloon left.

I'm not exactly sure but I think there was a scene the boy speaks to a toad (or frog) as well.

Overall, movie had heartwarming tones. Not sure of its nationality because I only saw it dubbed in my country's language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the Swedish [The Slingshot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107349/combined) from 1993.

> Stocholm in the 1920s. Young Roland lives with his socialist father, Jewish mother and a boxing brother. His mother sells condoms illegally, and from them, Roland makes slingshots which he sells. His rebellious ways has gotten him the special attention of his school teacher, who always makes sure that Roland is punished. Roland also tries to make extra money by repairing bicycles, a successful business that in the end lands him in hot water.

Everything you described is there. His mother shows people how to use them, and he first uses them as balloons and waterproof socks before settling on a slingshot. Here's the trailer, where you can also see him playing with the frog: